# Looping through an Array and performing a different action after the first match?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

As I've tried to structure below, I want an if statement that performs in a for loop to do one thing the first time it is processed, and something else every other time.

```
if (true) {
    for (value i : valueList) {
        if (i = true) {
             First time do this!
             Second time onwards do this!
         }

    }
}
```

Is there a function in java that allows me to do this?

Comment: As a note (i = true) sets i to = true you would need to use (i == true to check if i is equal to true)

Comment: @yitzih Ah, it's == in my program I just mis-translated it to here. Thank you though.

Comment: @CHill `if( i )` is better form than `if(i == true)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always used a flag, which gets unset in the first block to turn it off:

```
boolean first = true;
for ( value i : valueList ) {
    if ( i ) {
        if (first) {
            // First time do this!
            first = false;
        } else {
            // Second time onwards do this!
        }
    }
}
```

Note I removed the buggy assignment `if (i = true)` which is *always* `true`, *and* assigns `true` to `i` (clobbering your loop variable's value).

Also, the outer `if (true)` is unnecessary.

Comment: This is the best way, but I've always hated it. A language with an explicit contruct for this would be interesting.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Its the simple solutions like this I tend to overlook and overthink..

Comment: @cruncher I agree. This construct becomes so ugly with lambdas processing streams, I don't bother and go back to a java 7 loop

Comment: @Bohemian My tutor pointed this out to me yesterday too! Thank you. It was originally i == true in my code, but realised that might as well be if (i).